# Google Custom Search - How to modify results' text?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I'm using Google Custom Search on my website and I would like to modify results' text using Javascript - if possible.

This is the problem.

Every page's title has the following structure: "SITENAME - TITLE OF THE PAGE". I want to remove "SITENAME - " from the text of search results.

This is the JS code I wrote, but it doesn't work:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("search"); // Search results wrapper
var y = elem.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0; i < y.length; i++) {
  str = y[i].className;
   if (str.search("gs-title") != 0 ) {
     var newHTML = y[i].innerHTML;
     newHTML = newHTML.replace("SITENAME - ", "");
     y[i].innerHtml = newHTML;
   }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED (2020-08-27)**

Here's the solution, for which I have to thank **mplungjan** and **Andy**:

```
Callback = () => {
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".gs-title")].forEach(el => {
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/SITENAME - /, "");
    });
};

window.__gcse || (window.__gcse = {});

window.__gcse.searchCallbacks = {
    web: {
        rendered: "Callback",
    },
};
```

Comment: They might set restriction on search result data modifications. Check if the results are in iframe?

Comment: Results are shown by asyncronous JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `y[i].innerHtml` it should be innerHTML - here is a shorter version

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("#search div.gs-title")].forEach(div => {
  let html = div.innerHTML;
   console.log(html) // does this actually show sitename?
  div.innerHTML = html.replace(/SITENAME - /g,"");
})
```

Comment: Typo fixed, thanks. console.log(html) doesn't show anything, because [...document.querySelectorAll("#search div.gs-title")] gives an empty NodeList.

Comment: Your code is perfect: now it works (for me) using <script async>. But it's executed only once, while Google Custom Search script is executed multiple times clicking on pagination links (no page refreshing). In other words, I need your code to work for every block of results.

Comment: You need to move the code to the success of the search function

Comment: Yes, I'll try it. I'm going to take inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849144 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990108 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the callbacks API provided: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#search-time-callbacks

Comment: This is very useful to me. Thanks!